# Configuring a gridView adapter for use in a fragment accessing a SQLite database in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-sqlite, android-gridview

I am working on an appication that will show a gridView table that will be generated from a SQLite query on an ActionBar tab. I am very close to getting it, however am stuck on configuring the adapter. I would appreciate suggestions regarding this. TIA.

```
public class DataTable extends Fragment {
SQLiteDatabase db;

private DataTable adapter;
private int columnWidth;//added 3/25
ArrayList<String> surveyData = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
    DBAdapter msdb= new DBAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"adfg", null);     
    //db=msdb.getWritableDatabase(); 
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.datatable, container, false);   
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM surveyDB",null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        String path = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("P_path"));
        surveyData.add(path);
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);

/*problem   adapter = new DataTable(DataTable.this, surveyData, columnWidth);  
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter); */        
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.

```
 public class DataTable extends Fragment {
SQLiteDatabase db;  
ArrayList<String> arrCursor = new ArrayList<String>();  
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.datatable, container, false);        
    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);                
    DBAdapter msdb= new DBAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"adfg", null);     
    db=msdb.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM surveyDB",null);      
        c.moveToFirst();
        arrCursor.clear();
    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        String _id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        arrCursor.add(_id);
        String species = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("species"));
        arrCursor.add(species);
        String area = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("area"));
        arrCursor.add(area);
        String sampler = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("sampler"));
        arrCursor.add(sampler);         
        c.moveToNext();
    }           
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrCursor);
    gridView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);  
    return view;        
}
}
```